# Create a second (separate) register form within OpenCart 2?

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I know this has been asked once before but that question did not seem to have an answer within the thread. So I am posting a separate question.

Anyway so I am using OC version 2.1.0.2 . I need to create a second customer registration page which simple will ask them for a email address and password. (no other fields)

So I copied the below files

```
- catalog/controller/account/register.php
- catalog/model/account/customer.php
- template/account/register.tpl
```

I renamed the copied files to

```
- catalog/controller/account/registerb.php
- catalog/model/account/customerb.php
- template/account/registerb.tpl
```

I then edited the file in public_html/catalog/controller/account/registerb.php
with the below to point to my new file

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/account/registerb.tpl')) {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/account/registerb.tpl', $data));
    } else {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/account/registerb.tpl', $data));
    }
```

I then go to my newly created file at
www.fake.com/index.php?route=account/registerb 
However I get a error code 500 in my google chrome and the page will not load.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.

But I created files for you.
At mine server it is working when i run like index.php?route=account/registerb then it is shown like the following images:

[image: Different Register Form]

Download code from following sites:
[Download code for separate register page in OpenCart eCommerce](https://webocreation.com/blog/separate-register-form-containing-email-password-opencart-2-2)